# Resize image in Kendo UI Listview with JQuery

Tags: image, listview, resize, kendo-ui

I am trying to resize images in a Kendo UI ListView that is populated with data queried from a SQL database.

My ListView DIV and template:

```
<div>
    <div id="lvUserMainPics"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="lv-pics-template">
    <div id="profile-container">
    <div id="profile">            
        <div id="profile-photo">
            <div class="non-immediate-parent-container">
                <img class="main-img" alt="" src="#=Pic#" />
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

Here is my data source and ListView bind:

```
var sourceMainPics = new kendo.data.DataSource({
           transport: {
               read: "api/userpics/pics/main"
           },
           schema: {
               data: "Data",
               total: "Count"
           }
       });

       $("#lvUserMainPics").kendoListView({
           dataSource: sourceMainPics,
           template: kendo.template($("#lv-pics-template").html())
       });
```

As the ListView is binding the data, I would like to be able to call the following JQuery method to resize the images:

```
$('img.main-img').imgscale({
           parent: '.non-immediate-parent-container',
           fade: 1000
       });
```

Currently, I am able to get the images to bind int the ListView, but the resize isn't working.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do accomplish this?  If worse comes to worst, I can create different sized images during upload and save them to the server, but I wanted to try this route first.  Thanks for any help.

[UPDATE]

Working now by adding dataBound event to the ListView:

```
$("#lvUserMainPics").kendoListView({
           dataSource: sourceMainPics,
           template: kendo.template($("#lv-pics-template").html()),
           dataBound: function (e) {                   
               $('img.main-img').imgscale({
                   parent: '.non-immediate-parent-container',
                   fade: 1000
               });
           }
       });
```

Comment: When do you call `imgscale`? You should do it not when you create the list view but when the list view is populated with the data coming from the DataSource. Did you keep this in mind?

Comment: Rookie mistake... I had tried calling the function during the dataBinding event instead of dataBound event.  Working now.. thanks.